# Search array using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

I have an array of phone numbers, say:

```
var phoneNums = [
    8881749281,
    8881533241,
    9198421881,
    ...,
]
```

Its a much larger list than that (roughly 1,300 entries) but for simplicity, we will just use that.

The array is already in numerical order, but, I want to sort this array into many different arrays based on the area code.

So the logic would be something like this:

```
for loop
    if first 3 numbers of this entry != first 3 numbers of the next entry
         array.splice
```

I've just never had to do something like this using a regular expression before, so I dont really know where to begin.

I know the regular expression to get the first 3 numbers:

```
 const patt = new RegExp('^\\d{3}')
```

And doing something like this:
     var newArr = nums.filter(x => patt)

```
 for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
     console.log(newArr[i])
```

Is just giving me a list of all the full numbers, which isn't necessarily wrong, but I want it to just be the first 3 numbers.

Comment: `const patt = new RegExp('^\\d{3}')` or `const patt = /^\d{3}/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That doesn't actually solve the problem, and your proposed duplicate does not address the fact that a RegExp object cannot be used as a callback function for a filter.

Comment: Once the question is edited, yes, perhaps, it will no longer be a dupe. `new RegExp('/^\d{3}/')` just can't work, it is a common typo.

Comment: yeah I actually just changed that in my code and no it did not fix it. i realized i had done this pretty much right after typing it lol. ill edit it because i do think my question is different.